# Link Error 2001: Unresolved external symbol while porting 32 to 64bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio, 32bit-64bit, interlocked-increment

I'm trying to port a 32bit application to 64bit and have trouble with some interlocked functions, namely: `InterlockedIncrement64`, `Decrement64`, `Exchange64`, `CompareExchange64` and `ExchangeAdd64`.

The error:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_InterlockedExchange64" C:\path_to_object_file\myclass.obj

I already search for the error and found some threads, but none seemed to work. (E.g. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151728/unresolved-external-symbols-in-compiling-32-bit-application-in-windows-64))

I checked where kernel32.lib and psapi.lib are (/VERBOSE_LIB) and the solution from the link above did not help (giving full path to psapi.lib in Project->Linker->Additional Dependencies).

I also checked if the Vc++ Directories and especially the library directories did change between Win32-Version and x64, which they should and do.

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: It is declared inline in Winbase.h, very hard to guess why you'd get a linker error.  You'll need to show repro code.

Comment: Some part of the code looks like this: 
LONGLONG ( * Renamed_InterlockedExchangeAdd)( LONGLONG volatile *Addend, LONGLONG Value )
  = InterlockedExchangeAdd64;

Comment: Could someone help me at this please? The problem still exists.

I believe it has something to do with wrong library resolution but i don't know where Visual Studio loads the wrong/missing library.